# How can I define a function, which maps from a set to a partition of the other set?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I have two sets, let us say $M=\{m_1, m_2...\}$ and $N = \{n_1, n_2,... \}$. I want to define a function, which takes an element of $M$ and returns a partition of $N$, the unique one for every $m \in M$.

Would it be correct to define it in the following manner: $ f: M \mapsto 2^{2^N}$, where $2^N$ is a powerset of $N$? If not, then what definition would be correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set of partitions of $N$ is
$$\mathcal{P}(N) = \left\{\mathcal{U} \in 2^{2^N \setminus \varnothing} \mid \cup \,\mathcal{U} = N \mbox{ and } U, V \in \mathcal{U} \implies(U \cap V = \varnothing \mbox{ or } U = V)\right\},$$
which is a subset of $2^{2^N}$. So your function would be

$$f \colon M \to \mathcal{P}(N).$$